# Java - Ошибка запуска программы с аргументами в консоле

Tags: java, консоль, коллекции

В общем, без воды. На вход идет ссылка ( путь к файлу ) формата CSV, должна выводиться каждая строка ( массив ).
Для удобство скачал стороннюю библиотеку, для робот с CSV-файлами. Запуск через командную строку.
Компилирует хорошо, всё сделал правильно ( вроде ), прописал путь к библиотеке и т.д.:

```
E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company>javac -cp "E:\projects\Librari\opencsv-5.2.jar" QI100.java

E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company>cd E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src
```

Запускаю ( вроде... тут уже не уверен ) верно, указывая аргумент ( путь к файлу ), но выдает такую ошибку:

```
E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src>java QI100 C:\Users\ARTHUR\Downloads\file.csv
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class QI100
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: QI100
```

P/S Не серчайте.

---

Забыл о самом коде:

```
package com.company;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class QI100 {
    public void main (String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, CsvValidationException {
        String pathToFile = args[0];
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile));
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
        ArrayList<String[]> lineArray = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] line;
        while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
            lineArray.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Попробуйте название класса с package прописать E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src>java com.company.QI100 C:\Users\ARTHUR\Downloads\file.csv

Comment: Неа... Так тоже выдает эту же ошибку...:
**E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src>java com.company.QI100 C:\Users\ARTHUR\Downloads\file.csv

Error: Unable to initialize main class com.company.QI100

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opencsv/exceptions/CsvValidationException**

Comment: @arthur необходимо также добавить параметр -cp {путь к opencsv.jar}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src>java -cp opencsv.jar com.company.QI100 C:\Users\ARTHUR\Downloads\file.csv
```